# Excel Interop PageSetup values weird behaviour with or without typecasting

Tags: c#, excel-2010, interop

I open a file via Excel Interop and try to read the Heading and got differences between Excel and NPOI
After some investigation the weird behaviour condensed into this Testcase

```
        [TestCase]
        public void TestWeirdExcelBehaviour()
        {
            var excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();     
            // "mocking" a document with a heading
            excel.Workbooks.Add();
            excel.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&THeading";

            var nuxt =              excel.Sheets[1] .PageSetup.CenterHeader;    //&THeading
            var nixt = ((Worksheet) excel.Sheets[1]).PageSetup.CenterHeader;    //&UHeading

            Assert.AreEqual(nuxt, nixt); // nope they are not equal
        }
```

The difference is that `&T` was replaced by `&U` only by typecasting to `Worksheet`

From tesing in NPOI I am think, that the version with `&U` is the right one.

The basic question is why is this happening? Are there other similiar function, where typecasting in Interop makes a big difference?

I am using Excel 2010 and "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15.0.4795.1000"

Edit: condensed the testcase even more to remove language specific stuff

Edit2: Mapping Table of the placeholders I use

```
  Without cast   With cast  
 -------------- ----------- 
  &T             &U         
  &S             &P         
  &A             &N         
  &B             &A         
  &X             &X         
  &8             &8         
  &16            &16        
  &22            &22        
  &6             &6         
  &9             &9         
  &MFF0000       &KFF0000   
  &D             &D         
  &N             &F         
  &"             &"
```

Comment: Hmm interesting, I tried this with my English Excel 2016, but can't reproduce the behaviour you described, for me the values `nuxt` and `nixt` are the same.

Comment: Good to know. So it could be some kind of legacy stuff which was removed in Excel >2010 or language dependent (I use the german version of 2010)